# Significance of Clay Jensen's journey of getting his tattoo completed?

Tags: character, analysis, 13-reasons-why

In *13 Reasons Why* season 2, Clay Jensen tries to get a semicolon tattoo with Skye but he fainted before it could even get completed and he got only comma. But at the end of the season, he got the tattoo completed easily.

I know that semicolon tattoo significance as a means of suicide prevent and that [Selena and many cast member get this tattoo](https://www.seventeen.com/celebrity/movies-tv/news/a46301/selena-gomez-and-her-crew-got-matching-tattoos-for-13-reasons-why/) off-screen. But I want to know the significance of Clay's journey of getting this tattoo completed.

Answer (score 1):

Clay was trying to get the tattoo as a sign of being strong for Hannah, but he couldn't get it completed because he himself wasn't, and even though he was pretending to have moved on, he had not.
Getting the tattoo completed meant that finally he had let her go, and that he was ready to be to gather the strength he needed to accept her death after the whole trial.